# How to replace jQuery .val() function in javascript es6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am assigning a value to an element like the following.

```
$(element).val('abc');
```

I want to do the same in javascript es6. I tried with the following code but it is not working.

```
document.querySelector(element).value = 'abc';
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What type of HTML element is the target element?  What exactly is the selector you're using?  Please show a reproducible case for what you're trying to do.  Show the actual HTML and the actual selector you want to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `element` is already a DOM element, then you would just use:

```
element.value = 'abc'`
```

And, of course, this assumes it's the type of HTML element that has a `.value` property such as an `<input>` element.  If it's not, then we have to know what type of HTML element you are targeting.

You would only use `document.querySelector(element)` if `element` was a CSS selector string such as `"#submitbutton"` or `"#myform .password"` or some other form of CSS selector string that targets the desired element in the page.  If you show your actual HTML, we can help with how to target it with a CSS selector (if that's what you're trying to do).